# How to parallelize code where task is dependent upon value from previous task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some code something like the following. I would like to go ahead and start the next work item as soon as I have the `nextWorkItemNumber`. How could I modify this code to accomplish that?

I've never had the need to multithread something before where the next task in the loop is dependent upon a value obtained half way through the previous task.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    int nextWorkItem = 1;

    while(nextWorkItem > 0)
    {
       nextWorkItem = DoWork(nextWorkItem);
    }
}

public int DoWorkItem(int workItemNumber)
{
    // make service call for data
    // var nextWorkItemNumber = someNewValueBasedOnStuffAbove;
    // save results to database

    // return nextWorkItemNumber;
}
```

For simplicity it might help to think of the service call as a *random number generator* that takes a **second** to run. The actual scenario is more like I'm retrieving 100 records at a time from *Hubspot*, and I have to provide the starting point in the list from which to begin, however the list doesn't go up by ones and the only way I can give the starting point for the next request is to look at the id of the last record on the current request.

Comment: @MickyD For simplicity it might help to think of the service call as a random number generator that takes a second to run. The actual scenario is more like I'm retrieving 100 records at a time from Hubspot, and I have to provide the starting point in the list from which to begin, however the list doesn't go up by ones and the only way I can give the starting point for the next request is to look at the id of the last record on the current request.

Comment: @BVernon - Are you saying that you can't do the second call until you get the response from the first call? And then the third from the second, etc?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes. But I obtain that value half way through the method... so I need a way to get that information back to the main loop to start another thread while the current loop finishes its work.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm thinking I might be able to do it recursively, though my preference would be to learn a pattern that allows me to control the creation of threads from the top  loop rather than having to add that into the method that does the work.

Comment: @BVernon - Then split the second method in two. At this point I think I need to quote MickyD, "It's generally difficult to give threading advice to pseudo code".

Comment: @Enigmativity So if the service call is a random number generator, and for the database call just pretend it's a Console.Writeline() statement outputting the number. What additional information do you need? If you can show me how to do it with that, then I can apply it in my code. I think this answer would be far more helpful for others working with an example that simple as well, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. I have to run now so I will add some explanation later.

```
void Main()
{
    DoWork();
}

public void DoWork()
{
    var saves = new List<Task<(int workItemNumber, bool success)>>();
    int nextWorkItem = 1;
    while (nextWorkItem > 0)
    {
        var result = DoWork(nextWorkItem);
        saves.Add(DoSaveAsync(result.current, result.payload));
        nextWorkItem = result.next;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(saves.ToArray());
}

private Random _random = new Random();
public (int current, int next, object payload) DoWork(int workItemNumber)
{
    var next = workItemNumber + _random.Next(5) + 1;
    if (next > 20)
    {
        next = -1;
    }
    return (workItemNumber, next, new object());
}

public async Task<(int workItemNumber, bool success)> DoSaveAsync(int workItemNumber, object payload)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    return (workItemNumber, true);
}
```

For now, you'll note each save takes a second, but the overall time to run is just over one second.

Comment: Does this begin executing DoSaveAsync at the point it's added to the array, or at the point `.ToArray()` is called?

Comment: @BVernon - It's at the point that `DoSaveAsync(result.current, result.payload)` is called. So, when adding to the list. Calling `.ToArray()` doesn't cause a task to start.

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample:

```
var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var nextWorkItemNumber = 0;  // not ready yet

Task.Run(() =>
{
   // this will block inside the Task, until signaled
   manualResetEvent.WaitOne();

   // nextWorkItemNumber is ready now
   // do some processing here
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    // do some work to calculate nextWorkItemNumber 
    nextWorkItemNumber = 42; // because it's the answer to everything
    
    // signal that nextWorkItemNumber is ready
    manualResetEvent.Set();

    // keep doing more work if needed
});
```

Comment: Hmm... not sure if I completely understand how this applies, or if it can. This doesn't represent any kind of a loop where the result of each feeds into the next.